# Implicit Intent Not Working

Tags: android

I'm trying to open up a browser from my app.

Heres my code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But I keep on getting this error:

```
04-08 18:07:26.117 6133-6133/com.example.android.quakereport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.quakereport, PID: 6133
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4473)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:711)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
    at com.example.android.quakereport.EarthquakeActivity.startIntent(EarthquakeActivity.java:53)
    at com.example.android.quakereport.EarthquakeAdapter$1.onClick(EarthquakeAdapter.java:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here is my EarthquakeAdapter code:

`currentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = QueryUtils.getURL(positionNum);
                EarthquakeActivity ea = new EarthquakeActivity();
                ea.startIntent(url);
            }
        });`

And here is my QueryUtils code:

```
   `String url = "";

    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
        JSONArray earthquakesArray = root.getJSONArray("features");
        JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakesArray.getJSONObject(arrayNum);
        JSONObject propertires = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");

        url = propertires.getString("url");
        Log.v("JSON", "url" + url);

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON", "Error");
    }

    return url;`
```

I've already checked, and the url is working.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: Doesn't it say anything else? As the program and line number where the npe is being thrown?

Comment: Did you added INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: how do you add INTERNET permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> Add this in Manifest file after manifest tag.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: is EarthquakeAdapter's onClick method executed in the main UI thread?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire `EarthquakeAdapter` where this code resides.

Comment: judging from the error logs you are trying to open this in a fragment please post your whole click listener code for a little more code detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** create an instance of an activity yourself. Only the framework can create an activity successfully.

Get rid of:

```
EarthquakeActivity ea = new EarthquakeActivity();
```

Instead, if `EarthquakeActivity` is the activity that hosts the `AdapterView` that is using `EarthquakeAdapter`, pass the `EarthquakeActivity` into the `EarthquakeAdapter` constructor, so the adapter has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is related to startActivityForResult as it stated:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4473) at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
```

So it could be the problem with something this not with your Implicit intent

And `android.app.Fragment` is different than `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` make sure you imported correct one

And also make sure you added INTERNET permission:

To add Internet permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Add it in after manifest tag in Manifest file

It could be like:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```